# Type missmatch at Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, type-mismatch

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pdX0.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHF8f.png)

So.. I am trying to create an app with a list that tells me all the bluetooth devices that are connected, I used an youtube video to help me out with this, my code ended up exactly the same as his, I did review it plenty of times, but for some reason I keep getting this "type mismatch" error, and I have no idea what to do. I haven't tried many things, since I am pretty new to Kotlin, and to programmer stuff. If you can help me, I'd be really grateful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this wrong.
To be able to access the elements of the list, you need to write like this

Replace

```
val device: BluetoothDevice = list{position}
```

To

```
val device: BluetoothDevice = list[position]
```

Comment: Yo, thank you very much, it did work, I can't believe it was such a dumb thing, hahaha, I'm laughing right now, but thanks a lot for the help.